# how do I adjust the border according to the border-radius?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]
how do I adjust the border according to the border-radius,
do I need the border to adapt according to the border radius... ...

```
<div class="flex">
<div class="pil1">
<h1>a=Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="pil2">
<h1>sad</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 207px;
    border-radius: 107px;
    border: 10px solid transparent; /* Set the border color to transparent */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, gold, yellow); /* Add linear gradient background */
}

.pil1, .pil2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.pil1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 104px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 104px;
    background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_left_no_border.svg");
}

.pil2 {
    border-top-right-radius: 104px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 104px;
    background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_right_no_border.svg");
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .flex {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 20px;
        border: none !important;
        background: none;
    }
    .pil1, .pil2 {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 104px;
        background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_mobile_no_border.svg");
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .pil1::before,
    .pil2::before,
    .pil1::after,
    .pil2::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border-radius: inherit;
        border: 4px solid transparent; /* Set the border color to transparent */
    }

    .pil1::before,
    .pil2::before {
        border-image: linear-gradient(to right, gold, yellow); /* Add linear gradient border */
        border-image-slice: 1; /* Ensure the entire border is used for the gradient */
    }
}
```

Comment: Border radius does not work with `border-image`.

Comment: I know too but I need a solution